# No input file specified. (Laravel with homestead)

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm trying to set up laravel 5.5 working with homestead.

I've followed the steps [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead) up to and including  launching the vagrant box.

However, typing "dev.todoparrot.com" or "192.168.10.10" into browser brings up "No input file specified." error.

Trying

```
vagrant up --provision
```

(since I made changes to homestead.yaml) did not fix it.

My homestead.yaml looks like:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_rsa


folders:
  - map: D:/projects/todoparrot
    to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
  - map: dev.todoparrot.com
    to: /home/vagrant/Code/todoparrot/public
```

I've installed laravel 5.5 into "D:/projects/todoparrot" with composer. Running *php artisan serve* on this folder works normally - template site is found at http://127.0.0.1:8000/.

Running

```
vagrant ssh
```

or Putty and navigating to /Code and typing  `ls` returns the same files that are in "D:/projects/todoparrot", so the sync is working.

Comment: in `/home/vagrant/Code` you should already see the content of `D:/projects/todoparrot` so unless you get a subdirectory with the same name again, it will report the error.

Comment: I tried to use `ls` inside `/home/vagrant/Code` and it returns "operation not permitted" error. How do I check what files are inside it (if there are any)?

Comment: ^ nevermind, `vagrant halt` and back again fixed that

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
sites:
  - map: dev.todoparrot.com
    to: /home/vagrant/Code/todoparrot/public
```

to

```
sites:
  - map: dev.todoparrot.com
    to: /home/vagrant/Code/public
```

fixed my problem. Following tutorial without thinking about what I'm doing was the root of my mistake.